# Antenna microstrip feedline discrepancy?

Tags: rf, pcb-antenna, matching

I've been looking at some reference designs to guide my own design recently, and I noticed some possible discrepancies on one in particular.

This is the reference design:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidubq7a/tidubq7a.pdf (description)

http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00848?keyMatch=cc1310&tisearch=tidesigns (page and design files)

In section 9.3 it states the feed line was modified to be 50-ohms with the **1mm** thick PCB. The design files show a microstrip line width of **24 mils** and a spacing of **6 mils** from the ground plane on each side. However, doing the maths on these figures as a co-planar waveguide (with Saturn PCB toolkit) the impedance actually comes out more like *56-Ohms*.

Is this correct? And if so, is it just a case of the feed line being so short they don't mind it's a bit mismatched?

If it's not correct, how was it calculated? By my calculations the feed line would have to be about 33 mils wide to have the correct impedance.

Comment: What dielectric constant did you use? It varies with frequency to a greater or lesser degree depending on the specific PCB material. Note also that 10% is about the best you can hope for in a practical PCB without special tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is a coplanar waveguide *with ground*. See the layout - the bottom of the board is flooded in this area.

[image: Coplanar waveguide with ground]

[This calculator](http://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm) yields 50.13 ohms with a dielectric constant of 4 (a decent starting point).